# Php Soap Client doesn't answer after call

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to connect my server php with a soap client.
i'm using a basic call to a function but i don't recieve an answer.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://190.12.119.53:4333/wsdl/IDNLabResultadoWS?wsdl");
print_r($client->__getFunctions());//to get all function of Client
$parameters= array(
"parametro1"=>"valor1");
$valor = $client->ServicioRespuestaWSCanal1($parameters);
print_r($valor);
?>
```

Can anyone help please? 
Thank you so much